# Spring Boot @DataJpaTest stuck at HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, junit5

I have a JUnit 5 test that isn't working, it gets stuck as shown below:

```
2020-04-03 16:53:23.207  INFO 2788 --- [           main] .i.p.d.r.CustomerReferenceRepositoryTest : 
No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-04-03 16:53:24.153  INFO 2788 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : 
Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-04-03 16:53:24.590  INFO 2788 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : 
Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 372ms. Found 8 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-04-03 16:53:26.078  INFO 2788 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : 
HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-04-03 16:53:27.667  INFO 2788 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : 
HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-04-03 16:53:27.997  INFO 2788 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : 
HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-04-03 16:53:28.392  INFO 2788 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : 
HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-04-03 16:53:28.866  INFO 2788 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : 
HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-04-03 16:53:29.180  INFO 2788 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : 
HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect
```

The test is annotated like this:

```
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestDALConfig.class)
class CustomerReferenceRepositoryTest {
```

The test gets stuck and when I stop it manually I get this error messsage:

No tests found with test runner 'JUnit 5'

The test it self is very simple:

```
@Test
public void notNull() {
    assertThat(customerReferenceRepository).isNotNull();
}
```

The complete unit test

```
package <removed>.payment.dal.repository;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

import aero.sita.pts.ir.payment.config.TestDALConfig;

@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = Replace.NONE)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestDALConfig.class)
class CustomerReferenceRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerReferenceRepository customerReferenceRepository;

    public CustomerReferenceRepositoryTest() {
        super();
    }

    @Test
    public void notNull() {
        assertThat(customerReferenceRepository).isNotNull();
    }

}
```

The maven pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <artifactId>payment-dal-api</artifactId>
    <name>payment-dal-api</name>
    <description>payment-dal-api</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <ojdbc7.version>12.1.0.2</ojdbc7.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc7</artifactId>
            <version>${ojdbc7.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

TestDALConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses=ConfigRepository.class)
public class TestDALConfig {

    public TestDALConfig() {
        super();
    }
}
```

CustomerReferenceRepository

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Propagation;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import aero.sita.pts.ir.payment.dal.dto.CustomerReferenceDTO;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS, readOnly = true)
@Repository
public interface CustomerReferenceRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<CustomerReferenceDTO, Long> {

}
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?
Thanks

Comment: Please show the full code - including imports - as well as your Gradle or Maven build file.

Comment: @johanneslink I've updated the details as requested. Thanks.

Comment: CustomerReferenceRepository and TestDALConfig may also be important.

Comment: Just chiming in to say I'm having the same issue.  Junit4, java 11, spring boot 2.1

Comment: @bigbenbt not sure if I solved this. I will check tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Got same issue. Anyone with solution? @SME did you get the solution?

Comment: @BhartiSharmaI I think my issue was that I had Transactional on an interface which doesn't work in Spring Boot apps, it has to be on a class. In truth I can't remember but that may have been the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In your application yaml or properties file , try updating below !

```
spring.jpa.ddl-auto: none
```

Answer (score 0):

Please verify the import in the entity class. For example for `Date`, the correct import is:

```
java.util.Date
```

Not:

```
java.sql.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run the project with a solution given by [Harsh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5892518/harsh), but any DB operations were not working, possibly because the lock, I was running some queries on Dbeaver. So after restarting DB, connection was reset and lock was removed and  I was able to run project even with `spring.jpa.ddl-auto: update`